# Initializing <StreamApp> with Data

Tags: getstream-io

I am using react native with native code. Using the 'react-native-activity-feed' library, I am trying to get Stream Feeds up and running on my app.

I have set up my stream account with an api key, app Id and app secret. Using firebase functions, I am creating a token server side for the user upon account creation and then saving that to the database.

```
const client = stream.connect(
    functions.config().stream.key_id,
    functions.config().stream.secret,
);
const userToken = client.createUserToken(user.uid);
admin.database().ref('users/' + user.uid ).set({
    token: userToken
})
```

Client side, I retrieve that token for the current user and then I pass it (along with app Id and app key) into the  object. I am expecting to get an empty feed with no errors but instead I get 'data undefined' error from Stream.

What else do I need to create client side or server side in order to start using the StreamApp Object?

```
import {StreamApp} from 'react-native-activity-feed



render() {
  const { currentUser } = this.state
  const {streamToken} = this.state

  let apiKey = Config.STREAM_API_KEY;
  let appId = Config.STREAM_APP_ID;
  userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
  let token;
  tokenRef = firebase.database().ref(`users/${userId}`);  
  tokenRef.on('value', (snapshot) => {
    token = snapshot.val().token;
  })

return (
      <StreamApp
      apiKey={apiKey}
      appId={appId}
      token={token}
     >
      </StreamApp>
    )
  }
}
```

Error:

TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'client.currentUser.data')

This error is located at:

in StreamApp(...)
...

Comment: can you include the body of the function that you use to create the token and also attach values for vars (including the final token)

Comment: I think that you need to wait for tokenRef to be retrieved and only then pass it to StreamApp. My guess is that in this case StreamApp gets an empty token

Comment: That was it, thank you!

Comment: glad to hear that, would you mind answering this question yourself? This could help future readers with similar problems :)

Comment: If you use the example that is created on your dashboard or the keys that are used on the react native tutorial  (or reactjs tutorial) you will have data on them

Comment: Struggling a bit with the implementation of this. Would be grateful if you could link your GitHub for this, or the code including the body of the function you used to create the token! Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being a problem with the render function being called before the server had returned the stream token.

To fix, I gave the page time to load the stream token from the server:

```
render() {
    if(this.state.loading) {
      return (<View style={[styles.container, styles.horizontal]}><ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" /></View>);
    }
    return (
      <StreamApp
      apiKey={this.state.apiKey}
      appId={this.state.apiId}
      token={this.state.streamToken}
     >
    </StreamApp>
    )
  }
}
```